# Set focus on the added item

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to make a list of items, double-clicking on one item makes it editable. Currently, while editing an item, clicking outside (ie, `blur`) or enter by keyboard submits the new value.

Now, I want to add a `+` icon to add item to the list. **After clicking on the `+` icon, I want the focus (and double-click) to be on the added item so that we could edit that directly.**

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

[JSBin](https://jsbin.com/piterawuwu/2/edit?html,output)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    input {
      font-size: 20px;
      border:none;
      background-color:transparent;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="Ctrl">
  <table>
    <tr ng-repeat="item in items">
      <td>
        <input type="text" value="{{item.name}}" ng-blur='eEditable = -1' ng-readonly='$index !== eEditable' ng-dblclick="eEditable = $index" ng-keypress="keypress($event)"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div ng-click="add()">+</div>
  <script>
    var app = angular.module('app', []);
    app.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
      $scope.items = [{ name: "item #1" }, { name: "item #2" }, { name: "item #3" }];
      $scope.eEditable = -1;
      $scope.keypress = function ($event) {
        if ($event.keyCode === 13)
          $event.target.blur()
      }
      $scope.add = function () {
        $scope.items.push({name: "new"});
      }
    }])
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using a custom directive. (I've kept JQuery because it has two useful methods: `focus` and `select`)

```
app.directive("customFocus", function() {
  return {
    restrict : "A",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch(attrs.customFocus, function(newValue) {
        if(newValue) {
          $(element).focus();
          window.setTimeout(function() { $(element).select(); }, 0);
        }
      });
    }
}
```

You can now apply this directive as an attribute to each `input` element:

```
<input 
    type="text" 
    value="{{item.name}}" 
    custom-focus='$index == eEditable' 
    ng-blur='eEditable=-1' 
    ng-readonly='$index !== eEditable' 
    ng-dblclick="eEditable = $index" 
    ng-keypress="keypress($event)"/>
```

The only required change in your controller is to set `eEditable` to equal the final index when you've added an item:

```
$scope.add = function () {
   $scope.items.push({name: "new"});
   $scope.eEditable = $scope.items.length-1;
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/3bkJa2FcbTm4uSZ95BNi?p=preview

This solution appears to be more elegant than [the pure JQuery solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42940046/25216), because with this solution the controller doesn't need to know about the rendered DOM elements.

One issue is that it could be telling a lie: if there is more than one element with "custom-focus='true'", you'll have undefined behavior with regards to which element will actually be awarded focus.

Comment: Why did you delete your jquery solution? It always works, right?

Comment: @SoftTimur - It worked, it just wasn't particularly elegant. :-) I like this one more, though it would have undefined behaviour if two elements were set to true at once.

Answer (score 1):

When I have a problem like this in angular, it's sometimes easier to resort to jQuery.

```
$scope.add = function () {
$scope.items.push({name: "new"});
$scope.eEditable = $scope.items.length-1;
window.setTimeout(function() {
      $("table tr:last td input").focus();
}, 0);
```

https://jsbin.com/yegokobuna/edit?html,output

I push the jQuery code into `window.setTimeout(..., 0)` so the code gets called after the angular framework has completed rendering the HTML elements.

This isn't a great solution. It's harder to maintain because the Controller code now requires intimate knowledge of the rendered HTML. If I were to, say, modify the view to display the items in a series of `div`s instead of table rows, then I would have to go and make a change to the controller code as well.